# How can I organize multiple references to the same object in Rust with reference counting?

Tags: rust, reference-counting, borrow-checker

I have a struct representing polynome and I want multiple polynomes to reference the same **mutable** `Aliases` object. In JavaScript, I'd create an instance of the `Aliases` object and assign it to `p1.aliases`, `p2.aliases` and so on. In Rust, as far as I understand, I need to use `RefCell`, which should perform reference counting, because there is no garbage collector in Rust:

```
extern crate rand;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::*;

pub struct Aliases {
    pub idx_to_name: HashMap<i16, String>,
    pub name_to_idx: HashMap<String, i16>,
}

pub struct Polynome {
    pub poly: BTreeMap<i16, f64>,
    pub aliases: RefCell<Aliases>,
}

impl Aliases {
    pub fn new() -> Aliases {
        Aliases {
            idx_to_name: HashMap::new(),
            name_to_idx: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
}

impl Polynome {
    pub fn new() -> Polynome {
        Polynome {
            poly: BTreeMap::new(),
            aliases: RefCell::new(Aliases::new()),
        }
    }
    pub fn clone(&self) -> Polynome {
        Polynome {
            poly: self.poly.clone(),
            aliases: self.aliases,
        }
    }
}
```

But I get compilation error in `clone()`:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:36:22
   |
36 |             aliases: self.aliases,
   |                      ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

what is the right way to clone `Polynome`, so that all clones reference the same `Aliases` instance?

Please note that this question is not duplicate of [How to represent shared mutable state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418584/how-to-represent-shared-mutable-state). Because if I try to organize reference with lifetime declaration as proposed there:

```
pub struct Polynome<'a> {
    pub poly: BTreeMap<i16, f64>,
    pub aliases: &'a RefCell<Aliases> 
}
```

then I get 'doesn't live long enough' problem instead of 'can not move out':

```
pub fn new() -> Polynome<'a> {
    let alias= RefCell::new (Aliases::new());
    Polynome {
        poly: BTreeMap::new(),
        aliases: &alias,
    }
}

     error[E0597]: `alias` does not live long enough
   |
24 |             aliases: &alias,
   |                       ^^^^^ does not live long enough
25 |         }
26 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 19:1...
```

How should I create Aliases instance if I need it to live outside ::new()?

Comment: Reference counting is done by `Rc` or `Arc`, not `RefCell`. You can put `RefCell` inside `Rc` to make it both mutable and reference counted.

Comment: @Shepmaster, please unmark this as duplicated, so people can contribute.

Comment: It's still a duplicate, the specific detail you need was in a comment. Since that appears to be hard to find, I've moved it into the accepted answer (it's also exactly what @interjay said — `Rc` or `Arc`).