# How to store a reference in a Vec and use this later on in Rust?

Tags: rust

I need to create a Vec to track the objects I'm creating and change it's states to use later. But if I use a clone when get object stored on vec, its state is not updated how do I do this?

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Movement {
  x: i32,
  y: i32,
}

fn main() {
   let mut current = Some(Movement { x: 1, y: 2 });

   let mut stack = Vec::new();

   stack.push(&current);

   current.as_mut().unwrap().x = 2;

   println!("m: {:?}", current);
   println!("stack.m: {:?}", stack.pop());
   current = None;
}
```

Comment: It depends, but most likely you need some combination of RC and RefCell, but you may want to consider adjusting your design. Rust does not make shared mutable state easy.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't store the structs in the get directly?

Comment: I'm capturing the mouse events and storing the position inside this struct, the code run in loop and switch the  current variable, in some point I iterate the vec accessing the values, the code is more complex than this, but  this express the Idea.

Comment: Maybe just store indices into your vector?

Comment: The storing all of the mouse events in the vector and tracking the index of the current event is likely to be easier.

Comment: You are violating a very important rule of rusts owhnership guarantees here: You can either have multiple const references or one mutable reference. You are storing a reference to `current` into you `stack` and in the very next line you are requesting a mutable reference. That doesn't work out very well. You need to synchronize the access, have a look at the [`std::sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/index.html#structs) module and choose one.

Comment: I feel like there ought to be a duplicate for this Q, but I could not find a good one. The ones I considered are linked in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to mutate something while holding a shared reference to it somewhere else. This is a problem because Rust assumes things behind shared (`&`) references will not be mutated, in order to prove your code is correct in multi-threaded contexts and in the presence of certain optimizations.

To fix it, you could tell the compiler to forget about multi-threading and skip those optimizations. One way to do that is using `RefCell`:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Movement {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut current = Some(RefCell::new(Movement { x: 1, y: 2 }));
    //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ put it in a `RefCell`
    let mut stack = Vec::new();

    stack.push(&current);

    // note: as_ref, not as_mut
    current.as_ref().unwrap().borrow_mut().x = 2;

    println!("m: {:?}", current);
    println!("stack.m: {:?}", stack.pop());
    current = None;
}
```

If you need to share the object around different threads, you may want `Mutex` or `RwLock` instead. If the thing being shared is something trivially copiable, like a single `i32`, you could use `Cell<i32>` (non-thread-safe) or `AtomicI32` (thread-safe). Collectively these are called *interior mutability* types because they allow mutation of the internal value through a shared reference.

But interior mutability only gets you so far. Putting references to local variables in a `Vec` is not very flexible because the `Vec` cannot outlive any of the variables that it references. A common idiom is to move objects into a `Vec` and use indices, rather than built-in references, to access them. Here's one way to do that:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Movement {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() {
    // this object will be moved into the vector
    let temp = Some(Movement { x: 1, y: 2 });

    let mut stack = Vec::new();

    // now we set `current` to be the index of the object in the vector, and use
    // `stack[current_index]` to refer to the object itself
    let current_index = stack.len();
    stack.push(temp);
    
    // you could also do something like this to get a mutable reference, but it
    // would prevent you from doing anything else with `stack` until you are done with
    // `current` (`stack[current_index]` does not have this limitation):
    //let current = stack.last_mut().unwrap()

    stack[current_index].as_mut().unwrap().x = 2;

    println!("m: {:?}", stack[current_index]);
    println!("stack.m: {:?}", stack.pop());
}
```

There are more options. For instance, you could put the `RefCell` in an `Rc` (reference-counted smart pointer) and clone it to share the ownership between the `Vec` and a local variable. In the absence of more information about your goals I would lean toward indexing the `Vec` in order to avoid the complication of shared mutation, but the design is ultimately your choice.

### See also

- [Cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618823/cannot-borrow-as-mutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-immutable) (and questions linked there)
- [How to represent shared mutable state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418584/how-to-represent-shared-mutable-state)
- [Situations where Cell or RefCell is the best choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831037/situations-where-cell-or-refcell-is-the-best-choice)
- [Need holistic explanation about Rust's cell and reference counted types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674479/need-holistic-explanation-about-rusts-cell-and-reference-counted-types)

Comment: _would prevent you from doing anything else with `stack`_ As far as i know it should behave roughly same with `index_mut` , can you explain if I am wrong? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1a63c7bfbaf35e05403ab89600f4f111

Comment: @ÖmerErden You are right, you can use `stack` again but not until after you're done with `current`. So something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0827cdaac6b0b3d85d5fa4c028615dfa) does not work. Storing only an index does not have this problem because an index does not borrow the `Vec` so every time you access `stack[current_index]` it uses a "fresh" borrow. (I edited the question to be more explicit.)

Comment: Now it is more clear thanks for the explanation. I assumed OP has the ownership of the objects and using Stack(DS) to find out the next object's reference, not all the elements of stack, this might still need to be clarified though. If it is like that OP can always access the current element by using `last_mut()`, but yes if OP wants to access arbitrary element from the stack then `last_mut()` will not be useful.

Comment: It's worked with the index solution, was a little complicated because I had to refactor a little bit but I avoided some borrow checker problems.

Answer (score 0):

To get a mutable reference to a value in a vec you can do the following:

```
let idx = stack.len() - 1;
if let Some(pos) = stack.get_mut(idx) {
  pos.x = 2
} else {
  ..
}
```

This specifically gets the last object you put in the `vec` with `stack.push(current)`. Note that I would then move the objects into the `vec` completely and not just references to them, and access them using the above method.
Here is your example corrected for this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Movement {
  x: i32,
  y: i32,
}

fn main() {
  let mut stack = Vec::new();
  stack.push(Movement { x: 1, y: 2 });

  let idx = stack.len()-1;
  let mut current = stack.get_mut(idx).unwrap();
  current.x = 2;

  println!("m: {:?}", current);
  println!("stack.m: {:?}", stack.pop());
}
```

Comment: The explanation is right but the code is very wrong. If you're going to post code in an answer please be sure it does what you say it will.

Comment: Using `last()` or `last_mut()` might be a better choice to emphasize stack behaviour(peek).

Comment: @ÖmerErden yes you are right, but i chose to focus on `get_mut` since OP said he might be accessing other elements too, so wanted to use a method that could be used for that too