# How to create an object that can build many other objects all of which have a mutable reference back to the builder object?

Tags: rust

I have a bit of a difficulty formulating my question concisely enough for a title. [Here is the mockup of what I am trying to ask.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6882c41c536bd6820f6045dae832ffb)

I have a `Thing` struct, a `ThingMaker` and a `ThingProcessor`. A `ThingMaker` must be able to create multiple `Thing`s that are then passed to a `ThingProcessor` to be used.

The catch is that a `ThingProcessor` needs to have mutable access to the `ThingMaker` that made the `Thing` so that the `ThingMaker` can update its internal state using feedback from the `ThingProcessor`. While in code provided there is only one `ThingMaker`, in my real project there are multiple, so the `Thing`s need to include information on what object produced them.

The naive approach of storing the mutable reference in the `Thing` does not work due to the fact that you cannot have more than one mutable reference to an object at a time, and a `ThingMaker` makes more than one object requiring it.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418584/how-to-represent-shared-mutable-state) that seems very close to mine, but I cannot seem to adapt it to my case. I could change the definition of `Thing` so it keeps a reference back to the
`ThingMaker` through a `RefCell`, but then how is `ThingMaker` supposed to make `Thing`s?

Comment: `Thing` can own a refcounted smart-pointer back to its maker, e.g. `Rc<RefCell<ThingMaker>>`.  See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=stable&edition=2021&gist=1305da664c7351791d2a4f916c329e62).

Comment: Another option is to have `ThingMaker` use interior mutability via `RefCell` (or other tool), so that you only need an immutable reference, `&ThingMaker`, in order to mutate it.

Comment: Right, so. @ChayimFriedman I just opened the playground from a google search and started writing code. It seems it defaults to 2018. The structures I described should not be self-referrential, that is, `Thing`s point to their makers, but not the other way around, as @kmdreko said.

Comment: As it stands, I had thought of both proposed approaches. Making the type use interior mutability would be clunky (imo at least. dont like using cells and refcells), so I hope to avoid that. Using a smart pointer may be a good solution, I just had a little bit of trouble figuring out how to construct the `Thing`s, thaks @eggyal for providing an example.

Comment: Another question: Apart from telling `ThingMaker` to update its internal state, does `Thing` need to access any other information about `ThingMaker` or can that `ThingMaker` be thought of us a "sink"?

Comment: @Dizzar you'll need a `Cell`/`RefCell`/`Mutex` or something with interior mutability to allow for shared mutability, whether its outside the type, `RefCell<ThingMaker>`, or inside, `ThingMaker { inner: RefCell }`, is up to you. The only other option that wouldn't is if the `Thing`s only had an *identifier* for what `ThingMaker` made it, and have the `ThingProcessor` do the lookup-by-id itself using some other structure.

Comment: Sounds like you're in a single threaded scenario, so to echo other suggestions you need interior mutability, just `RefCell` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in two ways. Using smart-pointers or introducing internal mutability to the `ThingMaker`.

### Smart-pointers

Using this approach we wrap our reference to `ThingMaker` in `Rc<RefCell>` so that we can have multiple mutable references to one object. There is a limitation to this method (correct me if I'm wrong) - you cannot easily make new `Thing`s from inside the `ThingMaker`s methods. That is because we cannot easily obtain the `Rc` reference to an object from inside said object. Note that neither cells nor `Rc` are thread safe, so if you have a multi-threaded environment use `Arc` instead of `Rc` and `Mutex` instead of cells. [Here is an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=stable&edition=2021&gist=1305da664c7351791d2a4f916c329e62) using `Rc<RefCell>` smart-pointer. (thanks @eggyal)

In this expample, we rewrote `Thing` to store a smart-pointer instead of a direct reference:

```
struct Thing {
    pub parent: Rc<RefCell<ThingMaker>>,
}
```

we then have to wrap our maker in a `Rc<RefCell>` smart-pointer, like this:

```
let maker = Rc::new(RefCell::new(ThingMaker { data: 16 }));
```

Which we then give to creation function to make `Thing`s:

```
ThingMaker::make_thing(&maker);
```

Later, we can access and mutate `ThingMaker` using a `Thing`s reference like so:

```
let mut parent = thing.parent.borrow_mut();
parent.data += 1;
```

`Rc` smart-pointer allows shared ownership of `ThingMaker` between `Thing`s, and the `RefCell` allows us to reintroduce mutability, seeing as `Rc` is an immutable pointer.

### Interior mutability

This method makes it so that we do not *need* a mutable reference to mutate our object, only an immutable one. As we can have as many immutable referenes as we want, we can make as many `Thing`s as we want. To achieve this we can use `Cells` and `RefCell`s (refer to documentation to see which one will be better in you case). Additionally, if you are in a multi-threaded environment, you can use `Mutex`, as cells are not thread safe. [Here is an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cdf9c31d9e22b9dc5310e6bc2bd35771) of using `RefCell` to introduce intrerior mutability. (thanks @kmdreko)

As you can see, the data of our `ThingMaker` was wrapped in a `RefCell`:

```
struct ThingMaker {
    data: RefCell<u64>,
}
```

Which we can then use to get mutable references to our data:

```
fn process_thing(obj: &Thing) {
    let mut data = &mut *obj.parent.data.borrow_mut();
    *data += 1;
    println!("New data: {}", data);
}
```

Note that we only need an immutable reference to mutate our object, so we can get away with only storing immutable references inside our `Thing`s:

```
struct Thing<'a> {
    pub parent: &'a ThingMaker,
}
```

Comment: To be fair, both approaches use interior mutability to solve the problem posed in your question.  The refcounted smart-pointers add "shared ownership", so that each `Thing` can "own" its maker: this avoids a whole host of lifetime shenanigans that would otherwise arise, but is actually separate from the mutability question posed.